# Question Edit invalidating existing answers

Tags: discussion, editing

A recent edit to [Has any of the US federal armed forces acted violently against civil movements / protesters?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/53706/has-any-of-the-us-federal-armed-forces-acted-violently-against-civil-movements) invalidates several answers with multiple upvotes. The original question had no date threshold. The choice of WWII as a threshold by an editor seems fairly arbitrary. My understanding from this question [Question editing that invalidates answers](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2692/question-editing-that-invalidates-answers)
 is that edits that invalidate good answers are to be avoided. Have I misunderstood? I don't want to get into an edit war with anyone.

Update:

The edit has been reversed, so this is no longer an issue.

Comment: And we get someone commenting on all the answers that they do not match the question. I don't have enough rep to revert the edit. If limited to after wwii and not by th op it should be a  new questions

Comment: As promised, I have removed all of my comments about "invalid" answers.